# How to change css class runtime in SAPUI5

Tags: sapui5

[image: Tile Container]

I've a custom tile. I want to add class/Change color  on top HBox which is right now light green.  so that color should be according to score  (red,brown,dark green or light green) shown below. if score is above 80 it should be dark green. How can I do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use CSS with custom data assigned to the HBox control. A formatter would help to assign appropriate classes to the HBox based on the value.

XML:

```
<HBox width="200px" height="150px" backgroundDesign="Solid" >
        <items>
            ...
        </items>
        <customData>
            <core:CustomData 
                key="style-class" 
                value="{path:'/props/DLES', formatter:'.formatter.formatStyle'}" 
                writeToDom="true"/>
        </customData>
</HBox>
```

Formatter:

```
formatStyle : function(v){
        if(v>80){
            return "darkgreen";
        }
        else if(v > 60){
            return "green"
        }
        else if(v > 50){
            return "yellow"
        }
        else if(v > 40){
            return "brown"
        }
        else{
            return "red"
        }
    }
```

CSS:

```
[data-style-class=darkgreen] {
 background-color: #01870e !important
}
[data-style-class=green] {
 background-color: #7fc257 !important
}
[data-style-class=yellow] {
 background-color: #ffc300 !important
}
[data-style-class=brown] {
 background-color: #b73209 !important
}
[data-style-class=red] {
 background-color: #e00404!important
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this:- This works if we have static id

```
$("#hbox_id").toggleClass('change_me newClass');
```

Comment: the problem is I'm not using jquery, its SAPUI5 framwork,